# Excel VBA Macros report from two separate sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Hey guys I have a problem I am trying to solve with excel and VBA/Macros  I have 1 sheet which has data on clients and the amount of hours the company worked for that client. I have already created a vba that creates a sheet with only the clients that are worked on for +40 hours example of the sheet below.

Example:

**Client------Client ID---Hours**

Client 2------6465--------46

Client 5------4873--------48

Client 8------6578--------64

The other sheet is a breakdown of employees that worked on these clients and how many hours each employee logged. (already arranged By ClientID in order)

Client ID------Employee------Hours

6465------------Joan----------20

6465------------Carl----------20

6465------------Susan--------6

4873-----------Bill---------15

4873-----------Nate---------15

4873-----------Jim----------10

4873-----------Joan---------8

5555-----------Jen----------8

5555-----------Dan----------8

4223-----------Andy---------12

4223-----------Carl---------4

and so on (including the employees who worked for clients in total of less than 40 hours)

Notice how the employees for client 6465 worked 20 hours, 20 hours, and 6 hours for a total of 46 (like the total in the first sheet) but for client 4223 theres only 2 employees Andy and Carl who worked 12 and 4 hours which is 16 and thats why that clientID doesn't appear in the first sheet shown above.

What I need to do is have a macro that uses the clientID in the first sheet and finds those clientIDs in the second sheet and creates a new sheet only with those clientIDs with employee names and hours of the first sheet as there are way too many client IDs in the second sheet because it is including all clientIDs and employees.  Basically I need to filter out a bunch of client ID's that don't add up to 40 or more hours, but since the first sheet already shows me which clientID's are +40 all I need to do is look them up by clientID on that second sheet which is already arranged by clientID.  Sorry if this is confusing let me know if there is anyway it can be done.  I am guessing there has to be some loop that checks every cell for that specific clientID and copies all of those clientID's and moves on to the next one.

So for the first part of the code which takes the ClientIDs and hours worked and only displays the ones above 40 hours I use this one

```
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">40", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
Selection.AutoFilter
```

This code basically takes only the clientID's with more than 40 hours and places them into another sheet.  Now I need to take that new sheet and grab the clientIDs of each of those and find those ClientID's in the other sheet that has the employees that work on each client with their hours related to that clientID...this I am not having any clue how to do because it is on two different sheet

NEW EDIT

Okay so I have more code now..the following code helps me combine both sheets into 1 sheet...now all I need is some sort of loop that checks for only those ClientID's in the first sheet and copies only those same clientID's in the second sheet to the new Combined Sheet.  somehow that has to be inside this code someway

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Add a new summary worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)

        ' Specify the range to place the data.
        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:D15")

        ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
        ' worksheet to copy all the data.
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
               "summary worksheet to place the data."
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        ' This statement copies values and formats from each
        ' worksheet.
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        ' Optional: This statement will copy the sheet
        ' name in the H column.
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

    End If
Next

  ExitTheSub:

Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  SO is not a code outsourcing platform.  Please share what you have tried and where you are stuck.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Comment: Sure, as soon as I get to my laptop I will give you the different code I have tried

Comment: chrismas007 I removed the answer and added it to the original question with part of the code I am using for the first step

Comment: I am adding more of the code I am using...this code helps me copy data from several sheets to 1 summary sheet which is what I need..it still doesn't check for specific Client IDs but its at least pasting data from 2 sheets into 1 sheet so now I need to just figure out how to add a loop of some kind inside this code to check for specific values in a cell (clientID) so that it only copies that data....I am looking at your new answer to see if that answers it :) Thanks!! I am adding my code to my question as edit.

Comment: Did you try my loop code in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will loop through all rows on your Employees sheet, look up the client id on the total hours sheet, and return an "Over 40" or "Under 40" in Col D next to each employee's row.  Then it is just a simple filter (which you already know how to code).

```
Sub CopyIt()

'Assumes ClientID is Col A, Employee is Col B, and Hours is Col C on SourceSht
'Assumes Client is Col A, ClientID is Col B, and Hours is Col C on HoursSht

Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, SourceSht As Worksheet, OverF As Worksheet, CCell As Range

Set SourceSht = Sheets("Name of Sheet with Employees")
Set HoursSht = Sheets("Name of Sheet with your Hours per Client") 'Do original one not the over 40 one

LastRow = SourceSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
    If Not HoursSht.Range("B:B").Find(SourceSht.Range("A" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then
        Set CCell = HoursSht.Range("B:B").Find(SourceSht.Range("A" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If CCell.Offset(0, 1).Value > 40 Then
                SourceSht.Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "Over 40"
            Else
                SourceSht.Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "Less than or equal to 40"
            End If
    Else
        SourceSht.Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "Client ID Not Found"
    End If
Next CurRow

  Cells.Select
  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Over 40", _
  Operator:=xlAnd
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
  Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: So for the first part of the code which takes the ClientIDs and hours worked and only displays the ones above 40 hours I use this one...I posted it as an answer as it wouldnt let me add it to the comment here

Comment: So the code should be placed in the (employee's hours sheet) but don't I first need to collect the specific clientID with +40 hours from the other sheet so that it can look it up in the employees sheet...what sucks is the employees sheet doesn't have a Total hours for each ClientID it just has the Client ID and the hours each employee worked on that ID...thats why the other sheet has the clientID and Total hours..kind of bad report making in my opinion but its what is given to me.

Comment: Okay I think I got it!! Thanks so much, There were a few little things to be changed.  Right before CCell = HoursSht.Range... you must have "Set" also when I set SourceSht = Sheet..its Sheets not Sheet.  Other than that it works!  I added a filter code right underneath and it works perfect by only copying the clients and companies with employees of only those on 40+ hours